# Unable to retrieve textbox value to JS

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a textbox in one JSP page where the username is entered.Then I have another "Settings" page where there is link for  "Change Password" where I have to do the validation username and password(password should not be same as username).But the lightbox for Change password contains only the oldpassword, newpassword and confirmpassword fields..I am writing a small function in JS to validate but the value of username is not reached  till the js..How to do this??? Please help..

My Admin page

```
function newcheckUsernamAndPassword(field, rules,i,options){
        alert("i am  in new method");
        var newpassword=field.val().toLowerCase();
        alert("new pas" +newpassword);
        var username='<%=Session("username")%>'
        alert(username);
//      var username = getValueUsingElementID('username').toLowerCase();
//      alert("Username"+username);
        if(newpassword==username){
            return options.allrules.changepassword.alertText;
        }


    }
```

code from webpage for Chage password

```
> <input type="password" style="width:150px" id="oldpassword" class="
> textBox validate[required,funcCall[checkOldpassword]"
> onfocus="jQuery('#authenticateform').validationEngine('attach',{Overflown:false})"/></td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td class="login"><label class="textLable"><msg:message
> code="label.newpassword" /></label><span
> class="redStar">*</span>&nbsp;</td>
>             <td class="login"><input type="password"
> style="width:150px" id="newpassword" name="newpassword" class="textBox
> validate[required,maxSize[30],funcCall[checkOldAndNewPassword],funcCall[newcheckUsernamAndPassword],funcCall[validatePasswordCriteria]]"
>             
> onfocus="jQuery('#authenticateform').validationEngine('attach',{Overflown:false})"/></td>
>         </tr>
```

Myadmin Page for Username

```
    <tr>
  <td class="tblComponent" width="120px" ><label class="tblLabel" for="username"><msg:message code="label.components.userid"/><span class="redStar">*</span></label></td>
  <td class="borderR tblComponent" width="120px" colspan="3"><input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" onfocus="jQuery('#adduserform').validationEngine('attach',{Overflown:false})"/></td>

  </tr>
```

HI ,,,any help

Comment: Can you post some code from your web page besides the js function?

Comment: HI...have posted the code please can u help me

Comment: Did you look at the two answers that are already given?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming that your problem is that* `'<%=Session("username")%>'` *is not being replaced by its intended session value.*

If this function is in a .js file, then it's probably just being served by the web-server as is.

To see what I mean, try putting this function in the JSP page (instead of the .js file) and the `username` session variable (given that it exists) will then be properly parsed and replaced by the intended value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are grabbing the field properly eg.

```
field = document.body.getElementById('the_id');
```

Then you should be able to get the value by going

```
var newpass = field.value;
```